# Segmentation fault in Bollinger Bands

Tags: c, arrays, debugging, segmentation-fault

I tried to make a program that prints the buy/sell dates of the stock in chronological order, using the Bollinger Bands. The Bollinger Bands is a tool that uses Moving Average(MA) & Standard Deviation(SD) of stock prices to determine the upper and lower bounds for buying & selling.

This program receives N, M, and stock prices for N days. Then, the bounds are obtained by using MA&SD of stock prices from (n-M+1)th day to nth day. If the stock price of nth day is higher than the upper bound, the stock should be sold, and if lower, should be bought. When it is a buying day, '+' is printed before the date, and '-' when selling.

The code below reports segmentation fault, and I tried debugging through core analysis by which I could not succeed. I wonder why segmentation fault occurs in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long double average(int a[], int M, int n)
{
     int i;
     long double sum = 0;
     for(i=n-M+1; i<=n; i++)
     {
         sum += a[i-1];
     }
     return sum/(long double)M;
}

long double deviation(int a[], int M, int n, long double av)
{
    int i;
    long double temp, sum = 0;
    for(i=n-M+1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        temp = a[i-1]-av;
        sum += temp*temp;
    }
    return sqrt(sum/(long double)M);
}

int main()
{
    int N, M;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);

    int i;
    int a[N];
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", a[i]);
    }

    long double av, high, low;
    for(i=M; i<=N; i++)
    {
        av = average(a, M, i);
        high = av + 2*deviation(a, M, i, av);
        low = av - 2*deviation(a, M, i, av);

        if(a[i-1] > high)
            printf("-%d", a[i-1]);
        else if(a[i-1] < low)
            printf("+%d", a[i-1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
40 10
161 250 324 330 308 356 410 449 524 489 514 569 491 447 521 535 564 641 558 539 516 580 629 656 736 670 668 691 618 618 556 611 632 561 606 607 585 560 462 500
```

output:

```
-18-25+39
```

Comment: please give a input exemple and expected output. [edit] your question to include it in directly don't post it in comment !

Comment: input:
40 10 / 161 250 324 330 308 356 410 449 524 489 514 569 491 447 521 535 564 641 558 539 516 580 629 656 736 670 668 691 618 618 556 611 632 561 606 607 585 560 462 500

& output:
-18-25+39

Comment: I fix your code, but it's doesn't print the expected output, I let you handle the math, http://rextester.com/EUW52246

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass address of variable to `scanf()` otherwise it leads to undefined behavior possibly resulting in segment fault so please change:

```
 scanf("%d", a[i]);
```

to

```
 scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the second loop inside then main you ran it from M to N dose M is the upper-bound i believe then you should use `for(i=M; i<=N; i--)` , also c array index start from 0, so use `for(i= M - 1; i<=N; i--)` , and `scanf("%d", &a[i])`;